# GXT HandlerManager Bus Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, gwt, gxt

I'm search for a memory leak in a GWT application. I started with Chrome to create heap dumps and to compare them after certain actions.

In the summary of each heap dump I can see that after big amounts of arrays, Maps, HashMaps one of the biggest groups of classes is the HandlerManager.Bus class. Each HandlerManager.Bus item contains some Maps. Every click they accumulate in the heap and they don't get removed by the GC.

Starting GC manually also does not help.

Further reading shows that HandlerManager has got to do with ClickEvents and MouseEvents. I'm now looking for those events and source code where these are connected to fields of views and grids and other gwt/gxt code.

Please give a some hints what typically can go wrong with these classes.

I assume that there is some static classes and never lose the reference to this events and so the GC cannot remove them.

It is too bad that I cannot follow the memory objects in the heap as easy like I can do in MAT.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I've definitely seen that problem before.  You'll notice that all of the calls that add handlers return a HandlerRegistration.  Save these in a list.  When you are done with a class that contains a list of handlers, go through the list and remove each handler.  It's been a while since I've seen any GWT/GXT but I think it goes something like this.

```
List<HandlerRegistration> handlerList = new LinkedList<>();

public void addListeners() {
    handlerList.add(myComboBox.addListener(mySelectionHandler));
}

public void onClose() {
    handlerList.forEach(handler -> handler.removeHandler());
}
```